# cmake and isolated applications on windows

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

Considering a plugin system with the following installation pattern:

```
/install_prefix/main.exe
/install_prefix/plugins/plugin.dll
```

If my plugin depends on a library compiled as shared, its dll should be installed in the exe path:

```
/install_prefix/main.exe
/install_prefix/plugin_dependency.dll
/install_prefix/plugins/plugin.dll
```

I found [isolated applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375190(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used to keep the dependency side by side with the plugin as follows:

```
/install_prefix/main.exe
/install_prefix/plugins/plugin_dependency.dll
/install_prefix/plugins/plugin.dll
```

This relies on a manifest file generated with visual. I am using cmake to generate my projects and I can't find any reference on a "good" way to handle isolated applications in a cmake file.

Did anybody have this use case?

**EDIT:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335352/how-can-i-embed-a-specific-manifest-file-in-a-windows-dll-with-a-cmake-build) propose answers on how to embed an already existing manifest file. What I would like is a way to generate the manifest file in the build process, in a perfect world with something as simple as installing exports. Something like:

```
install(
    TARGETS target_name
    MANIFEST target_name.manifest
)
```

This would generate the manifest file and embed it with the target.

Comment: You write .manifest file by hand and then install it along your library using CMake. What's the problem with that?

Comment: As a lazy programmer, I was hoping for some kind of `install(MANIFEST my-plugin-name)` which would generate and install the file in just one line, without the "by hand part"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I embed a specific manifest file in a Windows DLL with a CMake build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335352/how-can-i-embed-a-specific-manifest-file-in-a-windows-dll-with-a-cmake-build)

Comment: There is a way, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518526/2799037

Comment: @usr1234567 As I said in my last comment, my question is more about how to generate the manifest through cmake than how to embed it. See edited question