# How do I embed a manifest in my Cmake Application (without using VS)?

Tags: c++, manifest

So I've found a number of explanations on how you add a manifest to your C++ executable using Visual Studio, be that with CMake or without. However, it seems the Internet is entirely void of explanations on how you achieve such with any other IDE, especially when you use CMake.

Since I'm new to using manifests, I have practically no idea what I'm doing wrong. This is what I have in the manifest so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="My_Executable"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>This is my executable.</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="true"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

(I want to require the user to accept admin privileges when starting the application.)

This file is called "My_Executable.final.manifest" and is located inside my project directory ("CLionProjects/My_Executable/"). I created it using [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx) that Microsoft provided, so I'm assuming the syntax is fine.

According to [this link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/release/3.4.html#other), CMake is smart enough to embed a manifest file when such is added to the executable sources, so I have tried the following:

```
add_executable(My_Executable main.cpp My_Executable.final.manifest)
```

which did nothing (also no error messages), as well as adding this custom command, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335352/how-can-i-embed-a-specific-manifest-file-in-a-windows-dll-with-a-cmake-build/21098214):

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET My_Executable
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND "mt.exe" -manifest \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\\My_Executable.final.manifest\" -outputresource:"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}$(TargetFileName)"\;\#1
        COMMENT "Adding manifest..."
)
```

Which yielded the error `The system cannot find the file specified.` presumably because `mt.exe` is Visual Studio dependent (as the example was for VS).

So I still have no idea how I'm supposed to embed a manifest file into my application with CLion. Any leads would be much appreciated, as I've run across this issue numerous times, but have never been able to solve it.

TL;DR: How do I embed a manifest into my CMake application that prompts the user for admin privileges when starting the application, using CLion?

Comment: `$(TargetFilename)` in CMake is probably wrong. Try `COMMAND "mt.exe" -manifest \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\\My_Executable.final.manifest\" -outputresource:"$<TARGET_FILE:My_Executable>\;1"`

Comment: @Botje Unfortunately, that still yields the same error.

Comment: Stick an `echo` in front and try invoking that command by hand?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I've only ever worked with CLion's built in CMake. But where would CMake take the `mt.exe` from? As far as I know this is a file you download with Visual Studio's SDK, and I am not using Visual Studio.

Comment: It is part of the Windows SDK, which you can download separately.